# Vanilla node.js response encoding - weird behaviour (heroku)

Tags: node.js, heroku, encoding

I'm developing my understanding of servers by writing a webdev framework using vanilla node.js. For the first time a situation arose where a french character was included in a `json` response from the server, and this character showed up as an unrecognized symbol (a question-mark within a diamond on chrome).

The problem was the encoding, which was being specified here:

```
/*
At this stage we have access to "response", which is an object of the
following format:

response = {
    data: 'A string which contains the data to send',
    encoding: 'The encoding type of the data, e.g. "text/html", "text/json"'
}
*/

var encoding = response.encoding;
var length = response.data.length;
var data = response.data;

res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': encoding,
    'Content-Length': length
});
res.end(data, 'binary'); // Everything is encoded as binary
```

The problem was that everything sent by the server is encoded as binary, which ruins the ability to display certain characters. The fix seemed simple; include a boolean `binary` value in `response`, and adjust the 2nd parameter of `res.end` accordingly:

```
/*
At this stage we have access to "response", which is an object of the
following format:

response = {
    data: 'A string which contains the data to send',
    encoding: 'The encoding type of the data, e.g. "text/html", "text/json"',
    binary: 'a boolean value determining the transfer encoding'
}
*/

.
.
.

var binary = response.binary;

.
.
.                   

res.end(data, binary ? 'binary' : 'utf8'); // Encode responses appropriately
```

Here is where I have produced some very, very strange behavior. This modification causes french characters to appear correctly, but occasionally **causes the last character of a response to be omitted on the client-side!!!**

This bug only happens once I host my application on heroku. Locally, the last character is never missing.

I noticed this bug because certain responses (not all of them!) now break the `JSON.parse` call on the client-side, although they are only missing the final `}` character.

I have a horrible band-aid solution right now, which *works*:

```
var length = response.data.length + 1;
var data = response.data + ' ';
```

I am simply appending a space to every single response sent by the server. This actually causes all `text/html`, `text/css`, `text/json`, and `application/javascript` responses to work because they can tolerate the unnecessary whitespace, but I hate this solution and it will break other `Content-Type`s!

My question is: can anyone give me some insight into this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to explicitly set a `Content-Length`, you should always use `Buffer.byteLength()` on the body to calculate the length, since that method returns the *actual* number of bytes in the string and not the number of *characters* like the string `.length` property will return.

Comment: Trying this now - seems like it could be the issue! Out of curiosity, what are some of the implications of *not* setting an explicit `Content-Length`?

Comment: Node by default will send back a chunked response using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` if `Content-Length` is not explicitly set. This is especially useful when you want to stream data back and you don't know the length ahead of time. This would also help your particular cause since the byte length will automatically be calculated for you by node.

Comment: Cool, I may eventually scrap the explicit assignment then. In the meantime, though, your advice works perfectly! Thanks :)